# Can I install C# Razor .NET on XAMPP?

Tags: windows, iis, .net-framework, xampp, c#

I have been trying to install IIS (Windows 8) on my head computer. I ended up installing XAMPP on it, setting up the FileZilla server to work with Visual Studio Community 2015 FTP on my development computer (Windows 8.1 Laptop). FileZilla connects, and VS2015 reads my server. It uploads, everything is well, and I can edit it. Thing is when I launch into the server on Firefox and go to the Home page (Razor C# .NET, Default.cshtml) is shows me the code behind the website. Is there like an extension for C# .NET?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get IIS installed? It's going to be a lot easier getting your ASP.NET app to run on IIS vs XAMPP.

Comment: Yes. I do have IIS installed on my host machine. But Visual Studio 2015 does not connect to FTP IIS, however FileZilla Server is perfect with VS. Can't seem to get a reliable (and working) FTP connection over IIS. My target is a home intranet, so port forwarding isn't an issue.

Comment: Thanks! Just setup FileZilla Server on its own (without XAMPP) to write to my IIS folder with elevated privleges. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure FileZilla to FTP files to your IIS website.  It should just be another directory on your file system.